NextJS App Router: How to access child component properties in layout?
To make use of the layout feature in the NextJS's App Router, I want to dynamically update the page title (<h1> tag, not metadata like <title>) on the layout depends on what the page component was loaded.
For example, when using a traditional create-react-app, I can do something like this:


// Page is the child component
const Page = () => {
  return (
    <div>This is page content</div>
  )
}
Page.title = "Cool Page Title" // Set the Page title

function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{Page.title}</h1> {/* Access the "title" properties */}
      <Page />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot( 
  document.getElementById("root")
).render(<App />)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>



(Or for a bit more complex use case, showing the usage of "title"):


// Page is the child component
// Generate 100 Page component for demo
const RANDOM_COUNT = 100
const PageComponentList = new Array(RANDOM_COUNT).fill(null).map((_,i) => {
  const Page = () => <div>This is the page content for Component {i}</div>
  Page.title = "Component " + i
  return Page
})

function App(props) {
  const ChosenComponent = PageComponentList[Math.floor(Math.random() * RANDOM_COUNT)]
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>This is {ChosenComponent.title}</h1>
    <ChosenComponent />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot( 
  document.getElementById("root")
).render(<App />)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>



However I am stuck on how to do a similar task in nextjs. Obviously I would not want to add a <h1> tag into every single page component.

in layout.js:

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>{children.title}</h1>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


in page component:

function Page() {
  return <div>This is page content</div>
}
Page.title = "Cool Page Title"
export default Page;

When rendering out, it doesn't show the <h1> tag, which is empty:

How can I achieve a similar technique in nextjs? I have think of using HoC, but it seems so old-school 2015.
Of course, if there's another better solution that can achieve a similar task, I am open to it as well.
Thank you!
Edit: The page title will be hardcoded, static, so would prefer server-side render friendly.

I don't have the full context of your problem, but in my opinon I think the H1 belongs on the page and not the layout. Since it is part of the content of the page. Say you would want a page without a title, then you would have to work around the current layout. Even if every page has a title, I believe we sometimes make things like this harder than it has to be by trying to not repeat ourselves.

@FelixEklöf Whether have title or not for the page, handling logics can be done in the layout file when rendering the <h1>, only if I can somehow access the "title" property.... Of course as mentioned, I am open to other suggestions that does a similar thing, but adding <h1> into every page doesn't seems to be good practice.

You can make your own layout.
make custom component and use this for every pages instead of root layout.
const Layout = (props) => {
    const {children, title} = props
      return(
        <main>
         <h1>{title}</h1>
         {children}
        </main>
      )
    } 
export default Layout

and use this on other pages.
    const Homepage = () => {
     return(
      <Layout title="Homepage">
        <p>this is homepage </p>
      </Layout>
      )
    }


the only problem with this approach is that it doesn't make efficient use of nextJS rendering, layouts usually won't re-render but not in this case.
